# Screen darkens, greys out, and freezes when running sofware centre or update manager

Tags: 15.04, update-manager, performance, acer, aspire-one

I'm running Ubuntu 15.04 on an acer aspire one 522 netbook. I do have a problem that a month of searching this Q&A Site still hasn't answered.

Launching the Ubuntu or Lubuntu software centre or update manager causes my screen to darken, lose colour and freeze. I always have system monitor running and check resources after an event and the only link I can see is that my incoming data spikes around the time of the incident...

*How should I proceed to get rid of this?*

Comment: You may have your software sources set to a particularly slow server, depending on wherever you are on the planet. Software Centre will try to load a list of updates, but has to wait for it to arrive. Look in `/etc/apt/sources.list` which server is used for software updates.

Comment: **John,**  Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  **;-)** Could you please go to a terminal by pressing [Ctrl][Alt][T] and copy-paste the following into your terminal: `free --human`, then [edit] your question and post the output of that command in there and leave a note @Fabby?

Comment: aspire@aspire-Aspire-One-522:~$  free --human
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          724M       660M        64M       8.2M       9.0M       105M
-/+ buffers/cache:       545M       178M
Swap:         745M       1.1M       744M
aspire@aspire-Aspire-One-522:~$ 
@Fabby.....this?

Comment: Update:  since initial post it has also happened launching Audacious and in firefox... incoming data has spiked on both occassions.

Comment: total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           723M        466M         54M         33M        202M        101M
Swap:          745M         68M        677M